# MVC DropDownListFor - Selected Value ViewModel Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying populate the selected value of a dropdown list. When I set the selected value on my ViewModel as a string, it works perfectly. When I set the selected value property as part of a subclass, it fails:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.JMASettings.CustomerID, Model.CustomerIDList)
```

This method works:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerID, Model.CustomerIDList)
```

1. Is it OK to have classes inside of the ViewModel?

   ```
   public class SettingsViewModel
   {
       public SettingsViewModel()
       {
           JMASettings = new JMASettings();
       }

       public JMASettings JMASettings {get; set;}
   }

   public class JMASettings
   {
       public string CustomerID {get; set;}
   }
   ```
2. Do you recommend that I copy and paste the contents of JMASettings into my settings view model class?

Comment: mybe help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809824/how-to-create-edit-view-with-a-dropdownlist?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: If the first is not working, then you should post your controller methods to see where the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sure. Your view model can contain whatever you like.
2. Not necessarily. There's no functional reason your first attempt using `model.JMASettings.CustomerID` shouldn't show the selected value. If it's not, then there's some other problem. You may not be properly populating the `CustomerID` property on `JMASettings` instance, or something in `ModelState` may be overriding what you set. `ModelState` is composed of values from `Request`, `ViewData` and `ViewBag`, *first*, and only values from `Model` as a last resort.

Comment: I had ViewData["JMASettings.CustomerID"] as a List<SelectListItem>, which caused the binding to fail to work. When I changed it to ViewData["CustomerID"], it worked successfully.  Make sure you don't have anything in ViewData that matches your property name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it OK to have classes inside of the ViewModel?

Yes it is OK, but probably not necessary.

> Do you recommend that I copy and paste the contents of JMASettings into my settings view model class?

Yes I recommend to move it to a single model as the subclass will require you to create a custom model binder.

Comment: While moving to a single model is OK, you certainly do not require a custom model binder if you don't.